Avg. no. of random points on d-sphere needed to cover the center in their convex hull?
If I draw points on the d-dimensional sphere (i.e., on the hyper-surface of unit-length vectors in d+1-dimensional Euclidean space) uniformly at random until their convex hull contains the center of the sphere (i.e., the zero-vector), then how many points will I need to draw on average?
My numerical simulations up to d=8 suggest that the answer is 2d+3, but I have no idea how to prove that...
(I am aware that the probability that the first d+2 points do it is $2^{-d-1}$, but the proofs for that fact that I am aware of do not seem to generalize easily to more than d+2 points, which we seem to need in order to then compute the average number needed.)

The generalization is Wendel theorem (see Wendel, "A problem in geometric probability").

You're right, I found out they had a formula for $f(N) := P(N$ random points don't suffice). But that does not suffice to solve the problem unfortunately.

If we could naively assume that the events "the first N points don't suffice" and "the first N+1 points don't suffice" were independent (which they are not), then $f(N)$ could be interpreted as (essentially) one minus the CDF of the sought survival distribution, and so to find the expected number we could simply build the sum of $f(N)$ until $N=\infty$. But this would give the obviously incorrect result of $d+2$, which is too small. The problem is that when I already know that the first $N$ points did not suffice, the probability that the first $N+1$ points don't suffice is $>f(N+1)$.

Actually, that probability is apparently $f(N+1)/f(N)$. This gives us the problem of evaluating the following sum: $\sum_{N\ge n+1}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{N\choose k}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{N-1\choose k}}$. I was not able to solve that yet.

You don't need independency, as expectation is linear even for dependent events. You need to sum probabilities of "we need to use $n$-th point" across all points, and these probabilities are precisely $f(N)$.

No, that's not correct. That would (as I said) give a result of (basically) d+2, which is obviously too small (because it is the minimal number of points needed, not the average number). I don't see what the linearity of expectation has to do with it.  The point is that we need the quantities $P($first $N+1$ don't suffice $|$ first $N$ don't suffice$) = P($first $N+1$ don't suffice$) / P($first $N$ don't suffice$) = f(N+1) / f(N)$.

I don't see how you get $d + 2$, and also why you need these conditional probabilities. For example, if $f(1) = 0.99$, $f(n) = 0.0001$ for $2 \leq n \leq 101$ and if $f(n) = 0.01$ for $1 \leq n \leq 100$, then expectation will be very different, but only one conditional probability will be different. Probability of needing exactly $N$ points is $f(N - 1) - f(N)$. Expectation is then $\sum N \cdot (f(N - 1) - f(N))$. Which telescopes to $\sum f(N)$.
